# Installing quill-image-resize-module results in creating "node_modules" inside of it with many modules

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install `quill-image-resize-module` via NPM. I have tried these commands `npm install --save quill-image-resize-module`, `npm install quill-image-resize-module`, `npm install -g quill-image-resize-module`.

All of them resulted in the same result. The result is, that the folder `quill-image-resize-module` getting created inside `node_modules`, then another `node_modules` gets created inside `quill-image-resize-module`. Inside this new, sub `node_modules`, many folders get created, e.g. `acorn`, `array-uniq`, `lodash`.

To sum up the issue, the NPM isn't installing the package, instead he's downloading many packages and putting them in a new folder inside `quill-image-resize-module`. Therefore, I'm unable to import the package.

```
import ImageResize from 'quill-image-resize-module'
```

This results in an error. The package does exist, but it doesn't have the files. It has another subfolder, and inside it, many other folders.

Log based on Old Pro's answer:

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'quill-image-resize-module' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\resources\js'
 @ ./resources/js/app.js 112:0-36
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss
```

Comment: Can you import *any* modules?

Comment: Yes. I have many vue-plugins and other quill plugins, which are already imported. I only have this issue because it's a nested `node_modules` inside the package folder.

Comment: I would consider filing a bug report, or at least ask the developer for any insight. This seems like a one of those strange issues.

Comment: Should I provide my package.json?

Comment: `npm i @appsflare/quill-image-resize-module`


This is the proper cli command for installing the dependecy.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@appsflare/quill-image-resize-module

Edit: if this works I will add the answer to the others :)

Comment: It's possible, though unlikely that your cache is corrupted. Have you tried `npm cache clean --force`, and then reinstall?

Comment: I just did. It shows the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me using Node 8.14.0 if I use `require` instead of `import`. Please post the error you get when you run

```
node -e 'require("quill-image-resize-module")'
```

My installation of `quill-image-resize-module` has 425 directories under `./node_modules/quill-image-resize-module/node_modules/` and the error I get is about `window` being undefined, which is normal for `node` but indicates that `quill` is expecting to be run in a browser, so your real issue may have nothing to do with the `npm install`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm running Node 10.14.1. I've run this in the project's terminal and tried to add the `require`. I have received the same error. I've updated the post and included the log based on your answer.

Comment: I am starting to think quill itself is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you delete your *node_modules* then you run `npm i quill-image-resize-module --save`, this should take a while to install, after it is successfully installed, you should have a tree of this:-

```
node_modules
├── quill-image-resize-module
│   ├── demo
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   └── script.js    
│   ├── node_modules             
│   │   └──         //Contains a long list of other dependencies
│   └── src              
│       ├── modules        
│       │   ├── BaseModule.js    
│       │   ├── DisplaySize.js  
│       │   ├── Resize.js  
│       │   └── Toolbar.js   
│       │
│       ├── DefaultOptions.js
│       └── ImageResize.js        
│   
|
├── .editorconfig              
├── .eslintrc
├── .npmignore    
├── CHANGELOG.md               
├── image-resize.min.js
├── npm-shrinkwrap.json  
├── package.json
├── README.md               
└── webpack.config.js
```

After which you can import the package as shown in the usage below:

### Usage

#### Webpack/ES6

```
import Quill from 'quill';
import { ImageResize } from 'quill-image-resize-module';

Quill.register('modules/imageResize', ImageResize);

const quill = new Quill(editor, {
    // ...
    modules: {
        // ...
        imageResize: {
            // See optional "config" below
        }
    }
});
```

This should solve your issue, but you can get to read more on [quill-image-resize-module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quill-image-resize-module).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Give this NPM package a shot `npm i quill-image-resize` or `yarn add quill-image-resize`

This is the proper CLI command for installing the dependency. `npm i @appsflare/quill-image-resize-module`

It was probably installing many other modules from other repos or something else since it was lacking the reference to the appsflare mono.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@appsflare/quill-image-resize-module

This `import { ImageResize } from 'quill-image-resize-module';` should work after using the proper install command, per the NPM documents.

Good luck, I hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, `Can't resolve 'quill-image-resize-module'`

Comment: I tried several things myself. Just to get this module to work. I think I am going to try and find an alternative, I think something isn't right with the repo. @Jaeger

Comment: Looks like @appsflare might have been a fork from this one https://github.com/kensnyder/quill-image-resize-module

Comment: Could be the reason for the nested stuff in node_modules

Comment: I just deleted the module's folder in node_modules. Should I install it in your way or?

Comment: I use Yarn, it really shouldn't make a difference, I just grok a lot of Facebook technologies as a React developer lol

Answer (score 0):

You can install `npm i --save quill-image-resize-vue` and use below code in your component:

```
import { VueEditor,Quill } from 'vue2-editor'

import { ImageDrop } from 'quill-image-drop-module';
import ImageResize from 'quill-image-resize-vue';

Quill.register("modules/imageDrop", ImageDrop);
Quill.register("modules/imageResize", ImageResize);

export default {
    name: 'ImageResize',
    components: { VueEditor},
    data() {
        return {
            content: '<h2>Here goes your content</h2>',
            editorSettings: {
              modules: {
                imageDrop: true,
                imageResize: {},
              }
            }
        }
     },
}
```

Official URL: [Quill image resize vue](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/quill-image-resize-vue)